# Can I solve this limit algebraically?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{{1}}{x^2}-\frac{1}{|x|}.$$

So I know that $|x|$ at $x<0$ is the same as $-(x)$, thus leading to

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{{1}}{x^2}+\frac{1}{(x)}.$$

And after a bit of simplification,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{1+x}{x^2}.$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}(1+x)\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

What do I do from here? I know that if you were to input $1/(-0.0001)^2$ you would be approaching $∞$. For $1+x$, you are going to get a value close to 1. But is there a way to solve this algebraically? I'm going to assume the limit of this function is $∞$, but I feel like I am not approaching this properly algebraically.

What do you think?

Comment: The numerator of the fraction you derive tends to 1, but the denominator tends to 0. Since this is a 1/0 case, there is no limit (it tends to positive infinity).

Comment: When you say tend to positive infinity, do you mean that the behavior of the function(from the left side) will approach infinity, but it is not accurate to say that the limit is infinity? (In other words, it doesn't exist?)

Comment: A limit must be finite if it exists. And infinity is not finite. It does approach infinity though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention,

when we find a limit $L$  such $\frac{A}{0}$ with $A\in \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$,

we look at the sign of numerator and denominator.

1. $A>0$ and $0^+$ , $L=+\infty$.
2. $A>0$ and $0^-$ , $L=-\infty$.
3. $A<0$ and $0^+$, $L=-\infty$.
4. $A<0$ and $0^-$ , $L=+\infty$.

Comment: So, by this convention, it is accurate to say the limit in this situation is $-∞$? $A$ being $1$ in this scenario, and we are looking at the left limit. 

The answer in my textbook states that its $+∞$ which is why I am unsure now

Comment: @user382540 No, you have here $A=1>0$ and $0^+$ cause $x^2\geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

For $x\lt 0$ one has $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{|x|}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{-x}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{x}=$.

For $x\gt 0$ one has $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{|x|}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{x}$ It follows

$$\begin{cases}\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}f(x)=\infty\\\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)=\text{ indeterminated form }\space \infty-\infty\end{cases}$$
However $$\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{x}=\frac{x-x^2}{x^3}$$ which is of the form $\dfrac00$ so we can apply l'Hôpital rule so we get the final limit being equal to $\infty$ because it is the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{-2}{6x}=\infty.$$